# javascript global variables - protection

Tags: javascript, security, variables, global

I am using some global variables on a web application, built on Html/Javascript. I am using these variables across pages (or portions of them), and sometimes they are used as post data for ajax calls. My question is: how secure is this? surely i can set different values for these variables (using a console for example) and then, the calls that rely on this var are made. Imagine the user sets some Id that corresponds to something that he even doesn't have access to..

How should this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Imagine the user sets some Id that corresponds to something that he even doesn't have access to." That is where serverside validation comes into play. If they do not have access, the server should know that and check that before doing operations!

Comment: right ... i was not discarding server side validation. Only setting some extra cloaking for client side :) thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing different about this from any web application, from a point of view of security.

Anything sent from the browser must be treated as untrusted by the server. This includes URL parameters, form post data, cookies, http headers and anything controlled by javascript. All these items can be manipulated by an attacker.

Essentially, it doesn't matter what the values are in the client, you only need to worry about them when they hit your server in the form of a new HTTP request (this includes XHR). Until that point, variables with bad values can't do any damage.

Ensure your server can correctly authenticate the current user and only allow them access to data and actions that they are authorised to perform. Ensure that all data received from the browser is checked to be correct (if known) or of the correct datatype and within expected limits, rejecting the data and aborting the action if it is not.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The others focusing on Javascript solutions or browser security seem to forget the OP's app could easily be attacked with curl from the command line spoofing all necessary data. If curl protected against it (why?) we could do it with any useful scripting language and it would be trivial

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery, you can use
[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

With this, you can associate the data with an element, thus a unauthorized user will not be able to access it

Comment: What would you do if I'd write my own Javascript function that sends whatever I want? @Cheekysoft's answer much better describes the situation.

Comment: Not true. An attacker can execute a javascript URL in the location bar, or console. Or just open up a javascript debugger, such as firebug, and change all the variable values whether they are global, local or in jquery metadata.

Comment: I would use singleton pattern to manage the global data. Hide those variables as the private member and only expose getter.

Comment: @Cheekysoft, if a user can't see an element at all, how can he select it and manipulate its data?

Comment: @Phil, just because you can not see an element, does not mean you can still read the code and figure it out. This is no way more secure that putting your front door key under your door mat.

Comment: @Phil, the entire DOM and javascript heap can be manipulated by user-supplied javascript. An attacker can even directly change the metadata by calling $( 'div#tralala' ).metadata( key, value ) if he wants. There really is nothing "hidden" about jquery metadata; it is as visible to the javascript programmer as any other variables, or data in the DOM.

Comment: I totally agree nothing can replace authentication. $.data is more elegant and more secure way to replace global variable. There are still wrong usages of $.data to make it insecure.

Comment: @Cheekysoft,what if $('#div#tralala') doesn't exist at all for the attacker?

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has runtime type identification (everything is a var like visual basic), its a loosely typed language.

Javascript has its own security model though

1. User cannot access files (r/write)
2. It cannot access or look at user location, files, open windows without demand etc

It is not possible to protect the source of your javascript file either or even pwd protecting it as this is better done server side.

Even encryption or decryption doesnt work because somehow you need to tell your users the key

Worse, JavaScript can self-modify at run-time - and often does. That means that the security threat may not be in the syntax or the code when it's delivered to the client, but it might appear once the script is executed.

There is no JavaScript proxy that parses and rejects malicious script, no solution that proactively scans JavaScript for code-based exploits, no external answer to the problem. That means we have to rely on the browser developers to not only write a good browser with all the bells and whistles we like, but for security, as well.