# Will defining js variable as global cause any security issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have defined global base_url in header

```
<script>
base_url = 'www.domain.com';
</script>
```

and during ajax or other js request on my own url from assets folder, i am using  `base_url` variable to fetch data from url. Will it cause any security issue in my website built using php framework?
Can attacker manipulate information on other users browser or any other manipulation?

Answer (score -1):

Because it can be overwritten. Imagine someone opens console and types

```
base_url = 'www.scam-domain.com'
```

To prevent this type of behaviour wrap code in anonymous function and call it immediately

```
(function() { var base_url = 'www.domain.com' })()
```

Than your variable is no longer in global scope and cant be changed from that place.

Comment: They can simply set a breakpoint in your code and reassign the variable when the debugger stops.

Answer (score -1):

Having global variables do not course extra security issues since you have to handle security from the back end.

Front end can be manipulated regardless having global or local variables.

Check this [javascript global variables - protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169331/javascript-global-variables-protection)

However having global variables in js is not a good practice but it depends on many things.

Check this too http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: One can change values of variables in their own browsers using console.
But can't change someone else's directly but can try something like XSS attack, virus, malicious plugin, etc,. Better not to trust anything from front end and make sure things are secured from the back end.

Comment: [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: If you're the service provider, then security risk in the frontend may not be YOUR problem, but it could certainly be for the client.